# How to add a dollar sign to a float input in Python?

Tags: css-float, dollar-sign

The program is simple and I'm still learning the basics, but I can't figure out how to put a $ (dollar sign) to a float input.

print("What is your name?")

fisrt_name: input()

#How can a $ appear after the user type a number?

print('How much would you like to give?')

amt1 = float(input())

I already tried:

amt1_dollar = "${:.2f}".format(amt1)

print(amt1_dollar)

But the output shows two numbers, the number the user typed and the print with a dollar sign.
How can I do to appear only the number with the dollar sign?
[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9TlQ.png)

Im sorry if the question is too stupid.... and thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new string, convert your float to string and add "$" symbol before it.
You should add your program language in tags.
You should use ``` to mark your code.
The "first_name" variable is not matter for this question, just delete it.

Think simple and clean code

Comment: I already converted the float in string, but how I add the dollar sign? Could you give me an example of the coding?

Comment: I don't know what programing language of your. but you can try to put "@" before String to get absolute string. <br>
JAVA example: String str = @"$100";